# Define the predicate Prolog

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I'm reviewing some exercise for the coming test and having difficulty at this.

> Given a list of integers L, define the predicate: add(L,S) which returns a list of integers S in which each element is the sum of all the elements in L up to the same position.
>
> Example:
>
> ?- add([1,2,3,4,5],S).
>
> S = [1,3,6,10,15].

So my question is what define the predicate means? It looks pretty general. I've read some threads but they did not provide much. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the predicate simply means write a predicate that does what the question requires.
In your question you have to write the definition of add/2  predicate( "/2" means that it has two arguments). You could write the definition below:

```
add(L,S):- add1(L,0,S).

add1([],_,[]).
add1([H|T],Sum,[H1|T1]):- H1 is Sum+H,NSum is Sum+H,add1(T,NSum,T1).
```

The above predicate gives you the desired output. A simple example:

```
?- add([1,2,3,4,5],S).
S = [1, 3, 6, 10, 15].
```

---

I think the above or something similar predicate is what someone would wait to see in a test.

### Some additional information-issues

The problem with the predicate above is that if you query for example:

```
?- add(S,L).
S = L, L = [] ;
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

As you see when you try to ask when your predicate succeeds it gives  an obvious solutions and for further solutions it throws an error. This is not a very good-desired property. You could improve that by using module `CLPFD`:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).


add(L,S):- add1(L,0,S).

add1([],_,[]).
add1([H|T],Sum,[H1|T1]):- H1 #= Sum+H,NSum #= Sum+H,add1(T,NSum,T1).
```

Now some querying:

```
?- add([1,2,3,4,5],S).
S = [1, 3, 6, 10, 15].

?- add(S,[1,3,6]).
S = [1, 2, 3].

?- add(S,L).
S = L, L = [] ;
S = L, L = [_G1007],
_G1007 in inf..sup ;
S = [_G1282, _G1285],
L = [_G1282, _G1297],
_G1282+_G1285#=_G1307,
_G1282+_G1285#=_G1297 ;

...and goes on..
```

As you can see now the predicate is in the position to give any information you ask! That's because now it has a more relational behavior instead of the functional behavior that it had before due to  `is/2` predicate. (These are some more information to improve the predicate's behavior. For the test you might not be allowed to use libraries etc... so you may write just a simple solution that at least answers the question).

Comment: The CLP(FD) version is a huge improvement, +1! Only one small suggestion: The imperative name `add/2` is no longer really appropriate for a predicate that can also generate and and test partial sums. Maybe you can come up with a more general name that more fully captures what this predicate means.

Comment: Thanks @mat, I chose this name because it was given in the question but I agree it could be much better.

Answer (score 4):

This is a good exercise to familiarize yourself with two important Prolog concepts:

- **declarative integer arithmetic** to reason about integers in all directions
- **meta-predicates** to shorten your code.

We start with a very simple relation, relating an integer `I` and a *sum* of integers `S0` to a new sum `S`:

> ```
> sum_(I, S0, S) :- S #= S0 + I.
> ```

Depending on your Prolog system, you may need a directive like:

> ```
> :- use_module(library(clpfd)).
> ```

to use declarative integer arithmetic.

Second, there is a powerful family of **meta-predicates** (see [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)) called `scanl/N`, which are described in Richard O'Keefe's [**Prolog library proposal**](http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/staffpriv/ok/pllib.htm), and already implemented in some systems. In our case, we only need `scanl/4`.

Example query:

```
?- scanl(sum_, [1,2,3,4,5], 0, Sums).
Sums = [0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15].
```

## Done!

In fact, *more* than done, because we can use this in *all directions*, for example:

```
?- scanl(sum_, Is, 0, Sums).
Is = [],
Sums = [0] ;
Is = [_2540],
Sums = [0, _2540],
_2540 in inf..sup ;
Is = [_3008, _3014],
Sums = [0, _3008, _3044],
_3008+_3014#=_3044 ;
etc.
```

This is what we expect from a truly relational solution!

Note also the occurrence of `0` as the first element in the list of partial sums. It satisfies your textual description of the task, but not the example you posted. I leave aligning these as an exercise.